# Random tag applied to every git commit

Tags: git, bash, github, docker, dockerhub

**Background:**

Docker Hub allows for autobuilding of images by pointing to Github and building on either-

1. commit made to a specific branch name
2. commit made with a specific tag name

Docker Hub also doesn't allow for versioning of images with the same tag, meaning that if an image is build with tag `:version_1`, and later, another image is build with `:version_1`, my original image is overwritten entirely.

I would like to be able to have a history of images. Pointing the autobuild to a specific branch name would mean, upon each commit (and subsequent image build), the prior image is overwritten. Therefore, I can't utilize #1 to accomplish this. But perhaps, I can leverage commit tagging!

**Desire:**

If I auto-generate a random tag, and apply it to a git commit, I could potentially have a history of images, where each commit has its own tag. The process of deploying an image from a specific commit then requires simply finding the random tag applied to that commit.

How can I apply a random tag (or perhaps, better yet, apply the SHA of the commit as a tag to itself (perhaps impossible)) to my commit?

I am not opposed to a bash script to solve this issue.

Comment: What about adding the current (date)time as a tag? It should make sure that they're unique and somewhat human readable.

Answer (score 0):

git rev-list master | while read sha; do git tag $sha $sha; done